# Spring boot bean deserialization issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Problem understanding the following issue. I have serveral Beans which are `SessionScoped`

```
@Configuration
@Profile({ "production", "integration" })
public class CloudConfiguration {
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CloudConfiguration.class);

@Bean
@SessionScope
public ConnectivityConfiguration getTenantConfiguration() {...

    @Bean
@SessionScope
public ConnectivityConfiguration getDestinationConfiguration() {...
```

Now these to Beans get injected via constructor into another Bean

```
@Service
@SessionScope
public class TenantInfo {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TenantInfo.class);

    private String tenantId;
    private String tenantAccount;


    public TenantInfo(TenantContext context) {
        LOGGER.debug("Creating TenantInfo");
        this.tenantId = context.getTenant().getId();
        this.tenantAccount = context.getTenant().getAccount().getId();
```

Now when I return the `TenantInfo` Bean in a Rest service

```
@Autowired
TenantInfo tenantInfo
    @GetMapping(path = "/tenantInfo")
    public TenantInfo getTenantInfo(HttpServletResponse response) throws RestClientException {
return tenantInfo
    }
```

I get the following deserializatíon error

```
Failed to write HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: No serializer found for class org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: com.tts.scp.converter.controllers.TenantInfo$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c90fa84a["CGLIB$CALLBACK_0"])
```

I can see in the Debugger that the Attributes of TenantInfo are Null(hence the error), but I don't get why, because I can see as well that the Contructor is run trough properly.
I tried using `@PostContruct` as well to the same end.

So the question I have is: What exactly is happening here? Why is the Bean seemingly properly created but afterwards all attributes are null?

Regards Mathias

Comment: Hi! I failed to understand where the `SessionScope`d beans are being injected in the _other_ bean via constructor. 

I don't see on any `@autowired` annotation on the constructor of `TenantInfo` class.

Comment: If you have a single Constructor you don't need @Autowire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the message; it's telling you exactly what you're doing wrong.

When you return an object from a handler method in a `RestController`, Spring tries to find a [HttpMessageConverter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/HttpMessageConverter.html) that can serialize that object according to the content negotiation. It makes zero sense to return a Spring bean from a method; there is no `HttpMessageConverter` that can take the bean proxy and serialize it on the wire.

Comment: Allright, I belive you but I am not getting the part about makes zero sense. I can return Pojos via `new TenantInfo(..)` without a problem and they get deserialized and there are BeanDeserializers as well, I wasn't aware that bean proxies can't be deserialized. So the Solution would be to write a Custom MessageConverter?

Comment: @MathiasMaerker Thanks but what I said is a fact, and fact doesn't need vote of confidence. Spring beans are meant for dependency injection - if your intent is to return `tenantId` and `tenantAccount`, you'd need to create a POJO, or as Spring calls it, a model.